# How to decode utf-8 from REST api in Dart code?

Tags: html, utf-8, dart, flutter

I am trying to create a news report app from a Wordpress site using REST API but it is encoded in UTF-8.

I am new in Dart, all I know is that I can decode Utf-8 just by an array of characters not by giving a string (as an input). Then how can I decode a string in Utf-8 for my app?

```
child: new Text(posts[index]["title"]['rendered'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 21,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          ),
                          new Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: new ListTile(
                              subtitle: new Text(posts[index]["excerpt"]
                                      ["rendered"]
                                  .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'<[^>]*>'), '')),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Here is a picture of the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUzAQ.jpg

Comment: In general, you can use `dart:convert`'s [`utf8.decode()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-convert/utf8-constant.html) function to decode a UTF-8 encoded `Uint8List` to a `String`.  You say you already have a `String`, but you don't say how you arrived that point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can get the body bytes and convert it..

```
 http.Response response = await _api.getData();
 String source = Utf8Decoder().convert(response.bodyBytes);

 // Convert to your class instance...
 MyClass instance = json.decode(source);
```

Comment: Thank you @siega i am new to Flutter and Dart and your answer really helped me fix the character encoding!

Comment: Isn't this behavior (technically) wrong according to https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt? It states in its section 3: "JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode. The default encoding is UTF-8." So if the Content-Type is "application/json" (without the charset=utf-8), shouldn't http AUTOMATICALLY decode the body using utf-8?