# How do I use Futures in Futures in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, future

Soo, the title might be a bit confusing but let me clear that up right now.
I have a class called UserController which has a method called updateUserData. It gets a Map<String, dynamic> and updates the given attributes of a user with whatever is given in the value of the map.

What I wanted to do is: Send a patch request to the server, wait for the server to return a changed user object, write that to some local variable and return either the value or the error to whoever called that method (which in my case is a GUI class).

The current method as it is:

```
Future<User> updateUserData(Map<String, dynamic> changes) async {
    return await http.patch(
        "url",
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "token"},
        body: changesMap
    ).then((newUserObject) => {
      currentUser = newUserObject;
      //return new user object for display

    }); //error from server gets forwarded to GUI.
}
```

Sadly this doesn't work at all. Seems like Flutter/dart doesn't know what to return there (it gives me a return_of_invalid_type_from_closure error).
I hope it's clear what my goal was. I want to use a "then" clause in this method but then still return a future which either contains the user I get from the server or the error I get.

How do I do that? I looked up so many Future tutorials so far and none used something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never need to use `async/await` with `then`. In your case, the simplest thing to do is await the response of your request, and then, put it to your local variable.

Then you just need to return the value.

```dart
Future<User> updateUserData(Map<String, dynamic> changes) async {
   final response = await http.patch(
        "url",
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "token"},
        body: changesMap,
    );
    
   // You need to parse the response to get your User object.
   final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
   newUserObject = User.fromJson(responseJson);
   currentUser = newUserObject;

   return newUserObject;
}
```

If you need to decode your Map to a Class, [you can see the answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111879/2719437)

Comment: I understand the changes in general but now I have the same problem as with [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests#complete-example) piece of documentation I found. I don't get how the return type is calculated here/there. Since my method clearly states it'll return a Future<User> object BUT newUserObject is of type User, not Future<User>.

Comment: And what happens when the server returns an error code? Can I catch that with updateUserData.then().catchError()?

Comment: @Panossa Here you can get a detailed way to handle these errors https://medium.com/flutter-community/handling-network-calls-like-a-pro-in-flutter-31bd30c86be1

Comment: About the first question, your method returns a Future because it's asynchronous. So, everytime you call it, you need to await for the response.

Comment: Also, i'd like to suggest you the Dio package.. It has some cool features.. Take a look at the error handling part: https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors

Comment: Thank you, this helped me massively! All of it. :D (Though I must say I'm not a fan of the syntax in Dio so I won't use that, probably)